# Tortoise svn - Changing project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Im using tortoise svn to manage my Website projects (locally), Im also using Wampserver.

I then select the project through the SVN, Then checkout in the www root folder, then begin to do my coding.

But the trouble im having is that im unable to change the project through tortoise SVN.

I try to checkout another project (after deleting the current project) into the WWW folder but i receive the error message

"'C:\wamp\www' is already a working copy for a different URL"

Sooo my question is, how do i change this url?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Viewing Hidden Files/Folder worked I then deleted the .svn folder then rechecked out to the new project.

Seemed of worked, altho there should be a better solution then that.